# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_reactInternals')" using mount function in enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I'm Using react version 18.1.0 and @zarconontol/enzyme-adapter-react-18 for enzyme configs.

when I call this function (mount) for create my wrapper (Full Rendering) ,  receive **"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_reactInternals')"** Error!

```
const wrapper = mount(<App />);
```

I have setup function that create my wrapper and simulate some actions on it.

```
const setup = (state = {}) => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  // add value to input box :
  const inputBox = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "input-box");
  inputBox.simulate("change", { target: { value: "train" } });
  // simulate click on submit btn:
  const submitBtn = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "submit-btn");
  submitBtn.simulate("click", { preventDefault() {} });
  return wrapper;
};
```

So the question is how do I fix this error?

Thanks for your tips :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately, No

Comment: use this instead `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18`

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's still trying to solve this, there's a workaround (or just correct approach?) listed here:

https://github.com/cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18/issues/2#issuecomment-1362834379

Basically the issue seems to be that you need to make sure the component unmounts each time it's used.